# convert latitude and longitude to northing and easting using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hi I am working with google maps for the first time...
I am getting lattitude and longitude but I want them to be converted to northing and easting using javascript and I can't find any approch for it...

Comment: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/

Answer (score 0):

A related question was asked here [Convert Eastings/ Northings to Longitude/ Latitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387218/convert-eastings-northings-to-longitude-latitude)

By following the link in one of the comments, I managed to find this, which may be useful to you.
http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/UsefulData/ConvertUTMNoOZ.HTM
(See the source for the in-line js and ask for permission if you want to use it).

Answer (score 0):

As JLRishe said, You can use proj4js to convert lonlat from google maps projection to utm.

Source projection is EPSG:3857 (Google Maps projection)

Your target projection should be like this

```
"+proj=utm +zone=<zone number> +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m"
```

[Here is algorithm that calculates zone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186496/determining-utm-zone-to-convert-from-longitude-latitude).

Or you can convert point to MGRS and take first 1-2 numbers and first 
letter.

```
var zone_number = new proj4.Point([lon,lat]).toMGRS().match(/\d{1,2}[A-Z]{1}/)
```