# Orbeon Forms: Convert Nothing/Easting to Lat/Long

Tags: orbeon

We need an Orbeon form to do the following:

1. Import the Northing/Easting values from the source app (we know how to do this)
2. Convert these Northing/Easting  to Lat/Long via an API (e.g. https://api.getthedata.com/bng2latlong/429101/624009)
3. Receive the Lat/Long values from the API
4. Construct a Google Maps URL (e.g. https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=54.63391%2C-3.20624)

I'm stuck with how to pass the Northing/Easting into the API, and how to extract the Lat/Long from the returned data (see test form https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/41dfb267bb328e5e40037c0ce049bd13d947cc9b)

Any help would be greatly received.

Many thanks.

PeteA

Comment: Useful info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387218/convert-eastings-northings-to-longitude-latitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. I think the main thing is that URL parameters in the HTTP service editor are for things that end up as `?easting=429157&northing=623009` in the URL, but you want to have those values as part of the path, as in `/429157/623009`. To do this, you need to use the following expression for the URL, which uses value templates, and the `fr:control-string-value()` function ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-form-runner#fr-control-string-value)), which results in the following URL.

```
https://api.getthedata.com/bng2latlong/{fr:control-string-value('Easting')}/{xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//Northing}
```

[image]

I have also updated your form on demo with those changes.

Comment: Many thanks as always - your help is very much appreciated.